# Declined flag on answer that likely violates T&C

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43441/2259) saying it was "of dubious voracity" and it was declined saying "this does not require moderator intervention".  I disagree; that answer should be deleted as it almost certainly violates the terms of the contest, and if not, is essentially blatant cheating and likely to get one banned or all their gifts rescinded ([a la TF2 idlers](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/94412-Team-Fortress-2-Punishing-Item-Idlers-Rewarding-the-Rest)).  The answer isn't simply *bad* but toxic.

I probably should have been more specific in my flag comment, but nonetheless, it's still a very bad post.  Yes, I and 4(?) of my cadre could delete it without moderator intervention, but it would need more downvotes.

Comment: So the downvote means those sorts of questions are OK to hang around?

Comment: In my opinion, yes.

Comment: Why on earth would we enforce someone else's terms unless failure to do so would be illegal?

Comment: I've already given my opinion as a comment on this answer: It's a valid answer to my question, although not one I'd accept.

Comment: @MatthewRead I honestly don't know, but is that why we don't answer questions about emulators and other forms of piracy?  We're not directly engaged in the act, so I don't know if we're doing anything illegal.

Comment: Torrent sites aren't actively engaged in piracy ;).  In general you can assume that aiding or actively enabling something illegal is also illegal. Aiding the breaking of a contract (terms of a contest, etc.) is different though.  Of course, I am not a lawyer, so don't blame me if Gaming is the first site to get sued for enabling contest cheaters :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure this is not against any kind of terms. Could you cite the relevant articles?

It's blatant cheating, yes, but it will not get you banned, nor will your gifts be rescinded. The answer is correct, factual and it works.

It might not be "the right way to do it" but I don't see any reason whatsoever to delete it.

Comment: There is precedent for [Valve to rescind gifts obtained through 'less-than-legitimate' methods](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/94412-Team-Fortress-2-Punishing-Item-Idlers-Rewarding-the-Rest)

Comment: @NickT No, there is not. That was about idling, not unlocking achievements. **Very** different case and not relevant at all. Valve did not rescind gifts for objectives unlocked using SAM in the summer sale.

Comment: Relevant-sounding excerpt from the [terms](http://store.steampowered.com/eula/2011_holidaysale_epicholidaygiveaway): "*Entries generated by script, macro or other automated means will be void. [...] False or deceptive entries or acts will render the entrant ineligible.*" In any case, Valve basically reserves the right to exclude you as they see fit.

Comment: @lunboks This isn't by script, macro or other automated means, unless you also define the game unlocking the achievement regularly as such. Additionally, the objective is merely to gain the achievement, not how, so arguably it isn't false or deceptive, either. At any rate, they didn't rescind and entries for the summer sale.